# ETH transfer to MultiSig contract keeps on getting reverted

Tags: multisignature, kovan

I am creating a [MultiSigWallet contract](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol).

I compiled and deployed the [MultiSigFactory contract](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWalletFactory.sol) to kovan network.

But when I transfer funds to the contract it gets reverted, as shown on [Etherscan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x432c3ac376403e3b490c0744e263047608168466bd68951a19ed3d727b725b92).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contract `MultiSigWallet` [implements a payable fallback function](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol#L94-L100), so you can transfer ether to it.

Contract `MultiSigWalletFactory` [does not implement a payable fallback function](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWalletFactory.sol#L8-L24), and [neither does its base](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/Factory.sol#L3-L42) (contract `Factory`), so you can transfer ether to it.

Comment: yes, I just realized that I should deploy the MultiSigWallet not the Factory.